# how to use multiple evals in html tags with two or more attributes asp.net

Tags: html, asp.net, sql-server

I draw the source of img tag from database using this code in my homepage.aspx file:

```
<asp:Image ID="Image4" runat="server" src='<%#Eval("coverBig")%>'>
```

and it works perfectly, But now I wanna use `srcset` html tag that uses two or more image addresses and the default form looks like this:

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" srcset="images/1.png 1000w, images/2.png 660w, images/3.png 296w"/>
```

I want to get img source from database using eval, here's the code that I tried out but doesn't seem to be working:

```
<asp:Image ID="Image4" runat="server" srcset='<%#Eval("coverBig")%> 130w,<%#Eval("coverSmall")%> 90w'/>
```

please give me the correct code form.

THANKS IN ADVANCE

Answer (score 0):

**First**, `<asp:Image>` has a valid attribute of `ImageUrl` and not `src`.

**Second**, `src` and `srcset` are attributes of `<img>` and `<picture>` tags respectively and are not asp.net elements.

Below code shows how `srcset` works -

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>

<picture>
  <source media="(min-width: 650px)" srcset="https://images.pexels.com/photos/531739/pexels-photo-531739.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350">
  <source media="(min-width: 465px)" srcset="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQjAWwspwgOqrtvbqz-THLRhmQ4TxBVg_9ZpqwZFb0NWJCjpqqA">
  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/19/08/33/flower-729512__340.jpg" alt="Flowers" style="width:auto;">
</picture>

<p>Resize the browser to see different versions of the picture loading at different viewport sizes.
The browser looks for the first source element where the media query matches the user's current viewport width,
and fetches the image specified in the srcset attribute.</p>

<p>The img element is required as the last child tag of the picture declaration block.
The img element is used to provide backward compatibility for browsers that do not support the picture element, or if none of the source tags matched.
</p>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> The picture element is not supported in IE12 and earlier or Safari 9.0 and earlier.</p>

</body>
</html>
```